# Kubernetes Deployments & Rollbacks

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

At the moment I'm performing Kubernetes deployments by applying `deployment.yaml` then updating the container/pod image versions with `kubectl set-image` as outlined in the docs. I'm doing this using Jenkins.

If I understand correctly, each time I apply `kubectl set-image` it updates the deployment in situ creating a new ReplicaSet meaning that I don't need to create a new `deployment.yaml` for each version bump.

Is this best practice or should I be creating a new `deployment.yaml` every time we bump version?

My next question concerns rollbacks, if I run `kubectl rollout history deployment/name`, I see three revisions but no 'cause'. I think this is because I've not specified `--record` on the initial deployment, and does that record each time we do a `set-version` too?

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be a good idea to update deployment.yaml for each version/release and commit to git so that later, any other person may follow through and even revert back to an earlier release/version.

Comment: You can also use helm or terraform so that you update image names/tags using environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

When we started to use Kubernetes at my current job we just re-applied the deployment manifest, updating the DATE on a annotation, this worked fine for some time, then we switched to use HELM https://helm.sh/

My recommendation is to switch to Helm since it manages deployments in a better way, even config maps are versioned between releases and also you can roll-back as you want.

Makes life easier when integration with CI/CD pipeline cause everything is parameterized/configurable.